# Convert list of variables to list of parametrized functions

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, parametric-functions, mapthread

I have a list of differential equations of some variables

```
eqns = {f[x,y,x',y'],g[x,y,x',y']}
```

e.g., `f[x,y,x',y'] = x x' + y y'`. I would like to parametrize the variables for entry into NDSolve. One option is to replace with

```
eqns /.{x'->x'[t],x->x[t],
        y'->y'[t],y->y[t]}

Out::
{f[x[t],y[t],x'[t],y'[t]],
 g[x[t],y[t],x'[t],y'[t]]}
```

But this is labor-intensive. When the number of variables (e.g., `x,y,z,w`) or number of derivatives (e.g., `x''[t]`) change, I need to manually add new rules (e.g., `z''->z''[t]`).

Is there a better way to convert variables appearing in expressions into functions of a defined parameter?

Comment: In the next version: `In[17]:= vars = {x, x', y, y'};
rep = Thread[vars -> Comap[vars, t]];
x x' + y y' /. rep

Out[19]= x[t] Derivative[1][x][t] + y[t] Derivative[1][y][t]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
param[eq_, v_:t] :=
 Replace[eq, {Derivative[a_][b_] :> Derivative[a][b][v], s_Symbol :> s[v]}, {2}]

eqns = {f[x, y, x', y', x''], g[x, y, x', y']};

param[eqns]
```

[image]

```
param[{f[x, y, x', y', x''], g[x, y, x', y']}, p]
```

[image]

Shorter, but also cryptic

```
param[eq_, v_:t] :=
 Replace[eq, {d_[a_][b_] :> d[a][b][v], s_Symbol :> s[v]}, {2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
eqns = {f[x,y,x',y'],g[x,y,x',y']};

Cases[eqns, s1_[s2__] :> s1[Sequence @@ Through[{s2}[t]]]]
```

[image]